# Array.size() returned wrong values (Grails)

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm developing an app using Grails. I want to get length of array.
I got a wrong value. Here is my code,

```
def Medias =  params.medias
println params.medias    // I got [37, 40]
println params.medias.size() // I got 7 but it should be 2
```

What I did wrong ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: How are you posting your params? Please paste a code for that

Answer (score 1):

What is params.medias (where is it being set)?

If Grials is treating it as a string, then using size() will return the length of the string, rather than an array.

Does:

```
println params.medias.length
```

also return 7?

You can check what Grails thinks an object is by using the assert keyword.

If it is indeed a string, you can try the following code to convert it into an array:

```
def mediasArray = Eval.me(params.medias)

println mediasArray.size()
```

The downside of this is that Eval presents the possibility of unwanted code execution if the params.medias is provided by an end user, or can be maliciously modified outside of your compiled code.

A good snippet on the "evil (or lack thereof) of eval" is here if you're interested (not mine):
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: as the `params` indicate, the code could as well be sent from the outside world, then using `Eval` would open the doors wide for a remote code execution.

Comment: Potentially true. I had made assumptions the OP would be aware of this potential risk. I will update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think 7 is result of length of the string : "[37,40]"

Seems your media variable is an array not a collection

Try : params.medias.length

Comment: It's probably just a string

Comment: No such property: length for class: java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: length for class: java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to everyone. I've found my mistake**

First of all, I sent an array from client and my ***params.medias*** returned **null**,so I converted it to string but it is a wrong way.

Finally, I sent and array from client as array and in the grails, I got a params by

```
params."medias[]"
```

Comment: You can also write like `params.list('media')`

Comment: if you are not sure, what you get handed down, then it's better to "debug" with `print obj.inspect()`.  the toString can be very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

List medias = params.list('medias')

Documentation: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#typeConverters